# Grails: how to collect all messages

Tags: grails, internationalization

I am new to Grails and I have inherited an existing application. I have a big file `message.properties` that I would like to prune, in order to remove keys that are no longer used.

In Django there is a command `makemessages` that goes through all codebase and collects all strings that need translation, adding them to the messages file and commenting out the entries that no longer exist. Is there a similar tool for Grails? If it helps, the project is based on verions 1.3.9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such tool, but you can create your own gant script. Take a look at [getting a list of all i18n properties used in a Grails application](http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2010/07/getting-a-list-of-all-i18n-properties-used-in-a-grails-application/) and process this list.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Cat, this is a starting point. It definitely needs to be made more robust and to be able to change directly with the `messages.properties` file. Another starting point would be the source for the equivalent Django command. https://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py If I have time, I will try to improve in it and share the results