# How can I create a map with all i18n-messages in Grails

Tags: grails

I need this to render a part of it in a controller like:

```
class MessageController {

  def index = {

    def messageMap = listAlli18nMessages() // the question

    render (contentType: "text/xml") {
       messageMap {key, message ->
          ..
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11773556/1342525

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I found an answer - override the default Grails messageSource:

```
class ExtendedPluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource extends PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource {
    Map<String, String> listMessageCodes(Locale locale) {
        Properties properties = getMergedProperties(locale).properties
        Properties pluginProperties = getMergedPluginProperties(locale).properties
        return properties.plus(pluginProperties)
    }
}
```

In grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    messageSource(ExtendedPluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource)  {
        basenames = "WEB-INF/grails-app/i18n/messages"
    }
}
```

Corresponding controller code:

```
class MessageController {
    def messageSource

    def index = {
        def messageMap = messageSource.listMessageCodes(request.locale)

        render (contentType: "text/xml") {
            messageMap {key, message ->
                ..
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, the extended message source wasn't being used. Maybe related to the following message I got at startup `java.lang.RuntimeException: Reloading agent exited via exception, please raise a jira Error | at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:104)` So, if at first this doesn't work`, fear not, just try again later and it will work

Comment: `request.locale` didn't properly work for me. I used `RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are taking doesn't look to be possible based on the API docs for [PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/context/support/PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource.html). This will get you close to a solution

```
class MessageController {
    def messageSource

    def index = {
        Locale locale = new Locale('en');
        List codes = ['default.paginate.prev','default.paginate.next','default.boolean.true','default.boolean.false']
        def messageMap =  messagesForCodes(codes,locale)
        render (contentType: "text/xml") {
             messageMap {key, message ->
                ..
             }
        }
    }

    private def messagesForCodes(codes, locale){
        Map messages = [:]
        codes.each{code->
            messages[code] = messageSource.getMessage(code,null,locale)
        }
        messages
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me. But the point is that I don't want to know all codes before.