# decorating Spring beans provided by Grails

Tags: spring, grails

I know that I can replace a Spring bean provided by Grails simply by defining my own bean with the same name. For example, if I want to replace the `messageSource` bean provided by Grails

```
class MyMessageSource implements MessageSource {
    // methods omitted
}
```

Then add the following in `resources.groovy`

```
messageSource(MyMessageSource)
```

However, assume that I want `MyMessageSource` to decorate the implementation of this bean provided by Grails

```
class MyMessageSource implements MessageSource {

    // this field should be set to the MessageSource impl provided by Grails
    MessageSource messageSource
}
```

I can't figure out how to wire this up in `resources.groovy`. Obviously I can't do this:

```
messageSource(MyMessageSource) {
    messageSource = ref('messageSource')
}
```

Because it looks like I'm defining a bean that depends on itself. I could of course give my bean a different name, e.g.

```
myMessageSource(MyMessageSource) {
    messageSource = ref('messageSource')
}
```

But then any class beyond my control (e.g. a plugin class) that declares a dependency on `messageSource` will be set to the bean provided by Grails rather than my decorator.

Comment: Take a look at `PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource` I think this is for loading messages from the plugins [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844201/how-can-i-create-a-map-with-all-i18n-messages-in-grails).

Comment: @Alidad this is indeed the Grails class which provides the `messageSource` bean by default, but this doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In an application (not a plugin), something along these lines should work...

The new message source:

```
// src/groovy/com/demo/MyMessageSource.groovy
package com.demo

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource
import org.springframework.context.MessageSourceResolvable
import org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException

class MyMessageSource implements MessageSource {
    MessageSource theRealMessageSource

    String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, String defaultMessage, Locale locale) {
        theRealMessageSource.getMessage code, args, defaultMessage, locale
    }

    String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, Locale locale) throws NoSuchMessageException {
        theRealMessageSource.getMessage code, args, locale
    }

    String getMessage(MessageSourceResolvable resolvable, Locale locale) throws NoSuchMessageException {
        theRealMessageSource.getMessage resolvable, locale
    }
}
```

A post processor:

```
// src/groovy/com/demo/MyPostProcessor.groovy
package com.demo

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException

class MyPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        // error handling ommitted for brevity here...

        def realMessageSource = beanFactory.getBean('messageSource')
        def newMessageSource = new MyMessageSource()
        newMessageSource.theRealMessageSource = realMessageSource

        beanFactory.removeBeanDefinition 'messageSource'
        beanFactory.registerSingleton 'messageSource', newMessageSource
    }
}
```

Register the post processor:

```
// grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy
beans = {
    myMessageSourcePostProcessor com.demo.MyPostProcessor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After the context is initialized you can retrieve the messageSource bean, create an instance of your bean that delegates to the messageSource bean and then register your bean with the context under the name "messageSource" so when DI happens, your bean is the bean that will be used.  In a plugin you should be able to do this in doWithApplicationContext (not doWithSpring).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you show an example of the Spring configuration that would achieve this in an application (rather than a plugin)