# Accessing messages.properties works in development but not when deployed

Tags: grails, internationalization, resourcebundle

The following code works fine when deployed locally in a dev environment from a controller (using run-app). It's used to create a JavaScript object with all messages in the current language.

```
class LocaleController {    
    private Map<String, String> getMessages() {
        // This is the line in question, the rest is just context
        def bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("grails-app/i18n/messages");
        def map = [:]
        bundle.keys.each { msg ->
            map[msg] = message(code: msg)
        }
        return map
    }

    def index() {
        header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=31536000")
        render(view: "index", model: [messages: getMessages()], contentType: "text/javascript")
    }
}
```

However, when this is run from a deployed server, I get the following error message

> errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - MissingResourceException occurred when processing request: [GET] /compose/locale/index
>   Can't find bundle for base name grails-app/i18n/messages, locale en_US. Stacktrace follows:
>   java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name grails-app/i18n/messages, locale en_US
>   at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
>   at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
>   at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1028)
>   at com.accelrys.compose.app.LocaleController.getMessages(LocaleController.groovy:13)
>   at com.accelrys.compose.app.LocaleController.index(LocaleController.groovy...

I would have preferred not to read the file directly, so I tried http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/11/grails-goodness-internationalize.html which uses http://grails.org/plugin/jawr but that page has been offline for the past 10 days.

I also tried following the steps in [How can I create a map with all i18n-messages in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844201/how-can-i-create-a-map-with-all-i18n-messages-in-grails) but it wouldn't use my customized message source, I copied the answer verbatim (clean/comile/run-app) but it was still using `PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource` instead of `ExtendedPluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource`

> 2014-09-29 17:15:33,447 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [GET] /compose/locale/index - parameters: jklgfdgdfg:
>   No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.context.support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource.getMessageCodes() is applicable for argument types: () values: []. Stacktrace follows:
>   Message: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.context.support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource.getMessageCodes() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
>       Line | Method
>   ->>   15 | getMessages in com.accelrys.compose.app.LocaleController$$EOrHmJbB

Any suggestions on what else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that [How can I create a map with all i18n-messages in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844201/how-can-i-create-a-map-with-all-i18n-messages-in-grails) does work correctly.

I am not sure why it wasn't working, as one can see from the error message in the question. Maybe it had something to do with the following error at startup.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Reloading agent exited via exception, please raise a jira
>   Error |
>
> at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform( ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:104)
>   Error |

In any case, if you try this and it doesn't work at first, don't give up. Try again later.

**Update**
It turns out that the reason the plugin didn't work was because `grails install-plugin` is deprecated, adding `compile ":jawr:3.5.1"` to the plugins section of BuildConfig.groovy made it work.